# NoneType error when converting tuple to list

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to select a row from a sqlite database. Make a number of changes then commit them back to the sqlite database as well as a mysql database.

The way I am trying to do it is by converting the `tuple` retrieved by the `SELECT` query into a `list` to make the changes.

```
key = 27361
c.execute("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE key = ?", (key,))
employeeTuple = c.fetchone()
employeeList = list(employeeTuple)
```

I am getting an error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Straight from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchone) "*Fetches the next row of a query result set, returning a single sequence, or None when no more data is available*"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cursor.fetchone()` returns `None` if there are no matching rows. You have no rows where `key = 27361` matches.

You can test for that possibility using `if employeeTuple` or using `or` to shortcircuit and assign `None` to `employeeList` in that case:

```
# if employeeTuple is None employeeList will not be set at all
if employeeTuple:
    employeeList = list(employeeTuple)
```

or

```
# if employeeTuple is None employeeList will be set to None
employeeList = employeeTuple or list(employeeTuple)
```

or

```
# if employeeTuple is None employeeList will be set to the empty list
employeeList = list(employeeTuple or [])
```